# the "medical issue" closing is really getting weak

Tags: discussion

So [here's a question from a few years ago](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7846/pain-on-the-top-of-my-foot?rq=1) that touches on pain while exercising. There are good answers, and it's great content for our site.

[Here's another from just now](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/26064/should-i-push-through-and-keep-lifting-if-my-knee-and-wrist-are-giving-mild-pain), that is already gathering the close votes because "you should go see a doctor."

Sometimes there are legitimate medical issues going on and people ***really*** should go see a competent provider. But anyone who's been training for a while knows that a core aspect of training is knowing your body, and one of the major ways your body speaks to you is through pain and discomfort.

A big part of physical fitness is knowing what and how to work with some types of pain. I feel like we're really knee-jerk kicking everything out these days the minute "pain", "discomfort", or "weird feeling" shows up.

There's just no way that every fit person is seeing a doctor every time they have a light muscle strain, etc.

Comment: Most of the fit people I know aren't going to doctors unless they are dragging the bleeding stump behind them. :p

Comment: It's a bit ironic, considering your vote on [this](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27900/my-leg-bone-starts-aching-as-i-do-my-workout)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed. Although I personally think that only questions on exercising with the injury are on-topic versus "I was lifting weights and now I'm coughing up blood, what should I do?"

**Good Questions (in my mind)**

- When I'm running, I sometimes get a pain in my side. Is this normal?
- I'm having trouble getting my leg behind my head without severe groin cramping. Is there any trick to make this easier?
- I have a huge blister on my foot. The pain is manageable, but should I keep running on it?
- [Shortage of breath - is this a sign of overtraining](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/27254/shortage-of-breath-is-this-a-sign-of-overtraining)?

**Bad Questions**

- I was lifting yesterday and now I've got rectal bleeding. Should I see a doctor?
- I'm a runner. My stomach has hurt ever since I had some bad shrimp last night. What should I do?
- I'm racked with pain every time I try to put weight on my right foot. Is my foot broken?
- Anyone know of a good chiropractor in the Estonian area?